# Oauth2.0, Is it safe to authorize using post request without redirect?

Tags: javascript, spring-security, oauth-2.0, pkce

So I'm trying to implement my own authorization server using spring. I have my front-end app which is implemented using ReactJs. One thing that I don't understand is that, why do I have to redirect to the login page on the authorization server side. I want to have nice and clean login page on the client side using ReactJs without redirecting to the other site. I mean, I trust my client (ReactJs app) anyway can I just use post request to make an authentication like this.

```
const login = () =>
// start loggin in
axios.post('/oauth/login_api_without_redirect',
           { username: 'usr', 
             password: 'pwd',
             client_id: 'react_app',
             ... scope, state, etc...
             code_challenge: sha_256('yyyy'), 
             code_challenge_method: 'sha_256' })
      .then(r => {
          axios.post('/oauth/token', 
                     { ... etc params ...
                       auth_code: r.data.authorizationCode, 
                       code_verifier: 'yyyy' })
      })
```

and on the authorization server side I would have this API.

```
@PostMapping("/oauth/login_api_without_redirect")
public String authorize(AuthenticationDTO authen) {
    // include client_secret and other stuff..
    return authorizationCode
}
```

Is that safe to do so.

Comment: if, let's say Google is used as IdP (identity provider) then an OAuth protected resource doesn't have access/control of Google login form, does a redirection to the login form, of course note that the resource provider establishes a trust relationship with the IdP (registers the app, get clientID and secret, ...), once authentication is done, redirects back to the resource. Research OAuth spec online, lots of diagram and detail explanation of the use case and flow.

Comment: @Patrick Have you found a satisfactory answer to this question? I'm curious whether OAuth 2.0 (first-party) is still a viable choice for trusted first-party mobile app clients or a first-party trusted single-page application (SPA), and whether there is a way to obtain a token directly via an HTTP request flow using user credentials obtained from the native mobile app's login screen.

Comment: https://www.ory.sh/oauth2-openid-connect-do-you-need-use-cases-examples/

Comment: https://www.ory.sh/docs/hydra/concepts/before-oauth2